# Can I add NSAttributedString in UIMenuItem's title instead of String?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I would like to add NSAttributedString in UIMenuItem's title instead of String, but I don't see any possible way of doing this. Is it even possible to maybe subclass UIMenuItem or something else to achieve this? I saw that on Telegram application on iOS they achieved something like this.
[Image with UIMenuItem from Telegram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8HtC.jpg).

Comment: It can be custom component that made by telegram. MenuItem does not have customizable view or label.

Comment: Custom Component you mean subclass of UIMenuItem or something else? Do you have any idea how they achieved this effect?

Answer (score 0):

This should allow you to use NSAttributedString for the title of your UIMenuItem:

```
import UIKit

class CustomUIMenuItem: UIMenuItem {
    init(titleAttributedString: NSAttributedString, action: Selector) {
        super.init(title: titleAttributedString.string, action: action)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let item = CustomUIMenuItem(titleAttributedString: NSAttributedString(string: "Menu Title"), action: #selector(testFunction))
        UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [item]
    }

    @objc func testFunction() {
        print("Success")
    }
}
```

Comment: This will discard all the styling in the attributes string. Which rather defeats the purpose.